# Need solution for Hover Issue

Tags: css, grid, hover, html-lists

I have an Product listing Page designed using ul li grid layout.The width of li is 171*367px.When the user hovers over the each li i need to 10px margin to all the sides of li and a box shadow as well.While adding the margin of 10px to each side the height of li increases and as a result the li while it expands pushes its adjacent elements.

I would need to achieve this without affecting the layout

Is there any way to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of margin use translate(x,y) property here x and y refers to coordinates of respective axis.

Comment: Do I need to add translate(10,10) instead of margin

Comment: Add transform:translate(10px,10px);